# Removing pages from a sub-document

Tags: finder, pdf, preview, printing

I have ten documents, 01.pdf to 10.pdf, that I would like to print. But some have cover pages that I'd like to remove. I'd like to avoid doing this manually ten times.

I'm halfway there. I can open 01.pdf using Preview, mark 02.pdf to 10.pdf in the Finder and drag to Preview's thumbnail section. Now printing will indeed print all pages. The trouble is that <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd> will not delete the occasional cover page, but the entire sub-document. Solution(s)?

I'm comfortable with any method (Terminal, MacPorts, ...), though using just Preview would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to print the document after assembling the sub-documents, and to then choose "Open PDF in Preview". The subdivisions between sub-documents will disappear.

At this point it's possible to delete individual pages using <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd>.